# Deleting end node of a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

Please help me understand why deleting last node like this isn't yielding right results

```
    def pop(self):
        temp=self.head
        while temp.next:
            temp=temp.next
        print("deleting this node: ",temp.data) #this confirms that last node is selected 
        temp=None
        print("deleting this node: ",temp) #this confirms that last node is None
```

Here's the print function I used:

```
    def printlist(self):
        temp=self.head
        while temp:
            print(temp.data,end=" ")
            temp=temp.next
        print("\n")
```

The last node is getting printed when I input, say, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
I pop the node containing 10 but it's still getting printed.

Instead when I use *temp.next.next* as the condition for while loop in the *pop()* function, I get satisfactory results

```
def pop(self):
        temp=self.head
        while temp.next.next:
            temp=temp.next
        temp.next=None
```

Here's my node class and Linkedlist class(of which pop and printlist are a part)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def pop(self):
        temp=self.head
        while temp.next:
            temp=temp.next
         
        temp=None
    def printlist(self):
        temp=self.head
        while temp:
            print(temp.data,end=" ")
            temp=temp.next
        print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code where you use `temp = temp.next` and assign `None` to it later, there are two things pointing to that node, the variable `temp` and the previous node of that node in `self.head`. When you assign something to `temp`, in this case `None`, you make `temp` point to a different value, not modify the original node in `self.head`. This type is called *value semantics* that focuses on the value the variable is holding.

However, if you change through `temp.next` in the second approach, you change it by reference. `next` in `temp.next` and in the corresponding node are referring to the same location. So once you change in either of them, the value held the other will be changed as well. This type is called *reference semantics*.

Comment: What do you mean by "the previous of that node in self.head"

Comment: Also, which node are you referring to when you say "there are two things pointing to that node"

Comment: For example in the first approach, temp is pointing to the last node so the previous node of temp is also pointing to that last node via `next`. Now `temp` in this case is a variable so when you assign something to it, it will hold that value completely. But if you change via `next`, you actually change the value referenced by `next`.